CSS not loading in LWR static site
I am starting a new brand new LWR static site project. Even though the CSS file is present in the folder, its throwing an error while loading in localhost. You can see from the below screenshot -

This is layout template njk file  -
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="$assetsDir/css/main.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <svg class="logo" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><path fill="#00a1e0" d="M23 6h22l-8 18h11L20 58l6-26H16l7-26z"></path><path fill="#032e61" d="M20 60a2 2 0 0 1-1.95-2.45L23.5 34H16a2 2 0 0 1-1.93-2.52l7-26A2 2 0 0 1 23 4h22a2 2 0 0 1 1.83 2.81L40.08 22H48a2 2 0 0 1 1.54 3.27l-28 34A2 2 0 0 1 20 60zm-1.4-30H26a2 2 0 0 1 1.95 2.45l-4.1 17.72L43.76 26H37a2 2 0 0 1-1.83-2.81L41.92 8h-17.4z"></path><path fill="#fff" d="M26 26a2 2 0 0 1-1.93-2.53l3-11a2 2 0 1 1 3.86 1.05l-3 11A2 2 0 0 1 26 26z"></path></svg>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a>
                    <li><a href="/about">About</a>
                     <li><a href="//developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/overview">Learn LWR</a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <main>
                {{ body | safe }}
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


Are you trying this on a Windows Machine? If yes, then it is miserable that the LWR build does not work on Windows, the module resolution is broken for Windows, and even Linux only works on Mac OS. I have raised multiple issues, but it is not fixed yet.

Her is the issue for your ref - https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/3979
